# Jena ConcurrentModificationException on DatasetGraph.clear()

Tags: exception, jena, concurrentmodification

I think I found a bug in the last Jena (2.13).

If I call clear() on a DatasetGraph (instantiated with  DatasetGraphFactory.createMem()) containing tuples of more than 1 graph, I get a ConcurrentModificationException.

You can reproduce the error with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatasetGraph dsg = DatasetGraphFactory.createMem();
        dsg.add(
           new Quad(NodeFactory.createURI("http://graph1"),
             NodeFactory.createURI("http://subj"),
             RDF.type.asNode(), 
             NodeFactory.createURI("http://someType")));
        dsg.add(
           new Quad(NodeFactory.createURI("http://graph2"), 
             NodeFactory.createURI("http://subj"),
             RDF.type.asNode(), 
             NodeFactory.createURI("http://someType")));
        dsg.clear();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Best,
Flavio

Comment: Using this minimal, complete example, this has been recorded as JENA-982 on the Apache Jena tracker and a fix applied.

Comment: Thanks for the support! Glad to be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to replace `dsg.clear` with

```
    dsg = DatasetGraphFactory.createMem() ;
```

and let the garbage collector deal with it. Or this:

```
    dsg.getDefaultGraph().clear() ;
    List<Node> graphNames = Iter.toList(dsg.listGraphNodes()) ;
    for ( Node gn : graphNames ) {
        dsg.removeGraph(gn); 
    }
```